# docker fails in pushing local image to repository

Tags: docker

I am just learning docker (I use windows 7 and install docker tools) and when I tried to use push command to push a local image to repository, it kept pushing for a **long** time without any prompts or error messages so that I have to use "ctrl+C" to stop it. I tried many times but got same results. 
the screenshot is as follows: 
[image]

I am not sure what is wrong with it. Maybe it's because I am now in China and it is due to the firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you pointed out that you're in China! Yes, this is very likely due to a Great Firewall issue.

`docker push` goes to `docker.io` as you can see; which returns the IP address of `34.234.103.99`

A WHOIS result of this returns that this IP address belongs to Amazon Web Services (AWS); which the Great Firewall blocks access to. After a cursory search, it looks like you're not the first to hit this as well.

I'd recommend setting up a VPN or proxy in order to bypass this.

Comment: emmmm... I use macbook and successfully pushed the image... maybe it is because of windows 7 that I was using...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and use the docker mirror that is hosted in china, see

- https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#use-case-the-china-registry-mirror
- https://www.docker-cn.com/registry-mirror (chinese)